# Issue setting the value within controller & strange result from console.log

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to set the value of some object and display it in the view however As you can see after setting the `vm.order.info.when` value into 'Any Value' and console.log the `vm.order.info` I get the value in the first half of the object right but when i extend the object I also see the same value as undefined.

```
vm.order.info.when = 'any value';
console.log(vm.order.info);
```

Is this normal and if so whats causing it ?

[image: Here you can see my console displaying the issue I was trying to explain]

Comment: Hover mouse over the blue "i" sign, it explains why you see this strange behaviour :)

Comment: I'm interested to know why too... could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try hovering over the blue `i` icon on the right side of the output. You will find the answer.

**Explaination:** When you are printing out the value by `console.log`, you get the value at the time when your code reaches the line `console.log(vm.order.info)`. But when you open the object inside the browser, you get the object which is formed when all your code runs/code that executed till you clicked to expand the object in the console. Thus, after your `console.log` statement, the code must have modified `vm.order.info` object, somewhere.

Comment: *"might be some browser issue"*. You think so? Try to hover over blue "i" sign.

Comment: Sorry! Got the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation it really helped, The problem was that I had ng-init somewhere in my view, assigning undefined value to my object.